# Pagination - Values of consecutive pages do not load

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am trying to implement pagination in my express application:

In my example I am loading the data from a [JSON file](https://github.com/marcpre/learning_pagination/blob/master/data/data.json).

My `app.js` file looks like the following:

```
const express = require("express")
const path = require("path")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express()

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"))
app.set("view engine", "pug")

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
}))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))
app.use(cookieParser())

//Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data/data.json', 'utf8')); 

    //pagination
    const totalRec = Object.keys(data).length
    const pageSize = 6
    const pageCount = Math.ceil(totalRec / pageSize)
    const start = 0
    const currentPage = 1

    if (currentPage > 1) {
        start = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
    }

    console.log("pageCount: " + pageCount + " totalRec: " + totalRec + " start: " + start)

    const postList = data.slice(start, start+pageSize)
    console.log("postList: " + postList)    

    res.render("index", {
        postList,
        totalRec,
        pageSize,
        pageCount,
        start,
        currentPage
    })
})

//Server
const port = process.env.APP_PORT || 8080
const host = process.env.APP_HOST || "localhost"

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Listening on " + host + ":" + port)
})

module.exports = app
```

Within my pug file I am trying to load further data:

```
  body
    .container-fluid
      .row
        .col-md-12
          h3
            | Mentoring 1
          a.btn.btn-primary(href='/new', role='button')
            | Create Post
          table.table
            thead.thead-inverse
              tr
                th Titel
                th Description
                th Created At
                th Tags
                th Action
            tbody
              //TODO: If post is empty
              each post in postList
                tr
                  td= post.titel
                  td= post.description
                  td= post.createdAt
                  td= post.tags
                  td
                    a.btn.btn-primary(href='/edit', role='button') Edit                     
          if pageCount > 1
            ul.pagination
              if currentPage > 1
                li
                  a(href='/?page=1')  &laquo;
              - var x = 1
              if currentPage > 5
                - x = x + (currentPage - 4)
              if (x !== 1)
                li.disabled
                  a(href='#') ...
              - for (x; x <= pageCount; x++)
                if( currentPage == x)
                  li.active
                    span.sr_only
                      = currentPage
                else
                  li
                    a(href= "/?page=#" + x )
                      = x
                if x == (currentPage + 4)
                  li.disabled
                    a(href="#") ...
                    - break
              if currentPage != pageCount
                li
                  a(href= "/?page=" + Math.floor(pageCount) ) &raquo;

      script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js')
      script.        

         script(src='/js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

My Problem is that if I use the pagination on the bottom I get the following URL back, `http://localhost:8080/?page=#2`, but no required data.

I have created a minimum viable example repo, which I hope describes my problem better:

[Pagination Example](https://github.com/marcpre/learning_pagination)

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong here?

I appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely related to 'attribute interpolation' not being supported anymore in Pug (see [this link to the Pug docs](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attribute-interpolation)). Basically, what this comes down to is that you can't use `#{...}` in attribute values anymore. You'll need to do something like this:

```
a(href= "/?page=" + Math.floor(pageCount) ) &raquo;
```

Comment: Thx for your reply! I changed the underlying code, still I do not get the required pagination output. Any suggestions why it is not working?

Comment: Is there any specific error output you're getting? Or is the URL of the link still not correct?

Comment: The link changes now correct to `?page=#2, ?page=#3, ?page=#4 etc.`, but I do not get any change in the data. Furthermore, there is no error message. I pushed the latest changes to the repo: https://github.com/marcpre/learning_paginat